# write pointers to pipe, are there any strict aliasing or pun type issues?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, pipe, strict-aliasing

I need to create many FIFO queues in a program, which is used for communication between threads in the same process.

I think I can use pipe() for this purpose, because in this way, I can use select or poll on the thread which fetch nodes from the queue.

```
        int* fd_pipe = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
        pipe(fd_pipe);
```

now the problem is how to put pointer into the queue
since each node is a strucutre, I want to put the pointer into the queue, something like

typedef{
   struct Packet *pkt;
   struct Info *info;
   int seq;
  }Node;

```
  on threads which put node into the queue:

   Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   Node->info = ...;
   Node->seq = ...;
   Node->pkt = ...;
   write(fd_pipe[1], node, sizeof(node));

  on threads which read node from the queue:

   char buf[1000];
   read(fd_pipe[0], buf, sizeof(node))
   Node* mynode = (Node*)buf;
```

then the mynode is what I want.

is there anything wrong in my program?
especially strict aliasing or pun type problems?
thanks!

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: I updated my code, you mean the cast ` Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));` is not necessary? are there any other problems in my source code?

Comment: `char buf[1000];` is definitely wrong. It's not an aliasing violation but an alignment violation. Instead you should be using `Node buf;`

Comment: but I have cast (Node *), isn't right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have aliasing issues.  Here the only issue I see is `read(fd_pipe[0], buf, sizeof(node))`, this should be `read(fd_pipe[0], buf, sizeof(Node *))`.

I am not sure why you use a char buffer here, I prefer

```
Node *node;
if (read(fd_pipe[0], &node, sizeof(node)) <= 0) {
    // error, deal with it
}
```

It's simpler and clearer.

Now, your code will only work as is if you use blocking i/o which is the default.  Also, technically, you should handle short read/writes but writing/reading on a pipe is atomic if the read/written size is less than PIPE_BUF (which is always much larger than a pointer)

You have a bit of a grey area in your code about memory synchronization before the write but since this is a system call, it will work.

A pipe is an unusual way to communicate between threads.  Usually, people use in-memory queues to communicate between threads.  One example is http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html

Comment: I‘M using `C` not `c++` and I want to use select/poll to poll the queue frequently, in-memory queue seems not adapted to this scenario?

Comment: I don't understand the grey area you mentioned, where is it?

Comment: I need to use select/poll on fd_pipe[0], why blocking I/O is necessary? what is short read/write. and from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712616/multithreading-read-from-write-to-a-pipe , it seems to me `read/write` is not atomic and should be locked using mutex?

Comment: If you do mean 'frequently', then I'd definitely use in-memory queue. The only case where I'd use a pipe is if you need to select/poll other objects.  I had missed your sentence saying that you're using select/poll so in this case, you're right you do not need blocking i/o.

The grey area I mentioned is that you need to make sure some form of synchronization is done so the thread reading from the pipe will see  the node as you set it up before calling write.  It's done through memory barriers.  Here you do not have any but since you're doing system calls, the kernel will emit some barriers

Comment: write is usually not atomic, you're correct.  However, writing from/to a pipe fd less than PIPE_BUF bytes is atomic.

Comment: so this means, I don't need to have a mutex lock on the pipe when the pipe is used by many threads at the same time? if all of the thread read/write less than PIPE_BUF each time?

Comment: Actually, I was not clear.  The atomic behavior is when using write.  I am not exactly sure it'll work on the read size.  If you're just reading a pointer, I *think* it'll work but not 100% sure